# Emitting variable from home.ts, need to catch it in popup.ts

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am emitting a value from `home.ts` and I want to catch its value in `popup.ts` . Pasting below `home.ts` code and `popup.ts` code. What do I need to do at `popup.ts` to receive it ?

`home.ts` code:

```
import { Component,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PopoverPage } from './popup';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @Output() chatEvent = new EventEmitter();    // 1

  public bring_on_popup = "I am from home";


  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.chatEvent.emit(this.bring_on_popup);
...
```

`popup.ts` code

```
import { Component , OnInit, Input, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';



@Component({
    template: `
      <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Learn Ionic</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Documentation</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Showcase</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">GitHub Repo</button>
      </ion-list>
    `
  })
  export class PopoverPage {
    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

    close() {
        //  console.log(this.bring_on_popup);
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

I believe I am emitting in the right way, I just need to catch **bring_on_popup** variable inside popup.ts

Comment: you are doing it backwards.. why not send through navparams when you create the popover

Answer (score 0):

Components in angular communicate in multiple ways, one of them is input and output, but to use this approach it needs to be child parent relationship between the connected components.

as example: If Component "A" needs to tell component "B" that the user has logged in.

Template (HTML file) of "B" component should contains something like this:

```
  <A (loggedIn)="onLoggedIn($event)"></A>
```

And TypeScript file of "B" component should contains the onLoggedIn method:

```
  private onLoggedIn(data:any){
        console.log(data);
  }
```

So on some action the "A" component will emit an event called "loggedIn" like below:

```
@Output() loggedIn = new EventEmitter(); 
private onLoginFormSubmit(){
    this.loggedIn.emit({username:"blabla", password: "blabla"});
}
```

Comment: this is output, how to catch the input ?

Comment: What do you mean by catch the input ?

Comment: you have emitted ` this.loggedIn.emit({username:"blabla", password: "blabla"});`  now how do i get these in another `.ts` file

Comment: When you put <A (loggedIn)="onLoggedIn($event)"></A> in "B" component template so you are telling the "B" component to call "onLoggedIn" method once the "loggedIn" output get fired. So the  private onLoggedIn(data:any){
        console.log(data);
  } will get called on every fire for output event